# CSS: Can You positiion a legend inside a fieldset on the left border centered?

Tags: css, sass, less

I am trying to take a legend and attach it to the left border. I want to display it center vertically. Is this Possible?
See the example below

Left border should look like this:

```
__________________________________
|
|
|
Some Text here
|
|
|
|__________________________________
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely position the legend, and then use a transition to correct slightly. The CSS looks like this (left padding added to the fieldset so the content doesn't overlap the legend):

**CSS**

```
fieldset {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

legend {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Title</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="radio"> <label for="radio">Click me</label>
    <div>
         <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You should note that this will lose the default styling of the `legend` and so the border "break" will not happen as it would normally - https://jsfiddle.net/gLxf3jvm/ This might be something the OP should consider.