# how to make border around text plus add number between line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I achieve something like the image below by using CSS, Bootstrap, or other client-side options?

[image]

Comment: You can start to code something ;) Nobody will code for you. Please provide us what you have tried and tell us where you got stuck, also read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will help you, i made it with custom css tricks, you can adjust font size according to your need.

```css
.outterCon{
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
}
.box{
  position: relative;
  border: solid 2px #000;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.legendCon{
  font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    left: -15px;
    top: calc(50% - 15px);
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outterCon">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="legendCon">01</div>
    <p><b>Quality</b>This is test text This is test text This is test text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check `fieldset` and `legend` tags,
W3C: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp

Comment: Will `fieldset` support displaying the legend on the left, as proposed by the OP? If so, you should include a code example to demonstrate how.

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105300/css-can-you-positiion-a-legend-inside-a-fieldset-on-the-left-border-centered

Comment: If this has been answered previously, you should flag it as a duplicate. The point of my question was to prompt you to add more details. On Stack Overflow, providing a link to an answer isn’t considered an answer. And suggesting some HTML tags isn’t especially useful if it’s not intuitive how to use them to solve the requested problem. Take a look at @dev’s answer as an example.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}
fieldset {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

legend {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: -15px;
  top: 30%;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Title</legend>
  <input type="radio" id="radio"> <label for="radio">Click me</label>
  <div>
    <label for="name">Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```